# How to get a field on string data in Ruby for Redis?

Tags: ruby, redis, unmarshalling

I have a dataset with the name of `table1` in Redis like below:

```
[
  {
    "column-name1": "10.1.10.1",
    "column-name2": "range(100,200)",
    "column-name3": "nam3"
  },
  {
    "column-name1": "2.2.2.2",
    "column-name2": "",
    "column-name3": "range(1024,+inf)"
  },
  {
    "column-name1": "1.1.1.1",
    "column-name2": "",
    "column-name3": "nam3"
  }
]
```

I want to get values of `table1`.. How can I do it?

How can I parse `table1` in ruby to reach its values?

Comment: What is `table1`? Redis doesn't have a concept of a table, it is a key-value storage. It does support several more complex data structures, but as far as I remember none of them could natively store the arbitrarily nested JSON (only serialezed one, with de/serialization logic on the app level)... So, could you please clarify the question? Ideally show the code (how you save data, how you retrieve them)

Comment: Did you consider using the RedisJSON module for Redis? https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/
https://github.com/vachhanihpavan/rejson-rb

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov `table1` is name (key) of a dataset (value) that I stored. I used key-value storage structure. I wanna search on value of `table1` with `ruby`.. how can I handle it?

Comment: @GuyKorland No I have not used RedisJson.. I'm using string data type of Redis.. creating data as json in python and saving on Redis as string. now I wanna search on them in Ruby.. I think It need unmarshalling data!

Comment: If it is just a string that is expected to be a valid JSON, you can simply parse it (see `JSON#parse`) and then search in an array of hashes (`Array#find`, `Array#select`, ...) (might be quite slow, but it is what it is with this data structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist, you should parse json data from stored string in Redis. For parsing json in Ruby you can do something like below:

```
require "redis"
require "json"

red = Redis.new(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379, db: 1) <-- connect to redis

table1 = red.get("table1") <-- get table1 value (stringified data)
table1_json = JSON.parse(table1) <-- parse value to get a JSON object
```

now you have your table1 data as a json object and you can iterate over its elements and get the values you want:

```
for key in table1_json
    puts(key["column-name1"])
end
```